# creating individual images of each plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have three vector in matlab and I want to plot them individually and save the result in jpeg files.
For the moment I do the code blew but it returns me all the curves in the same graphic. How can I separate them and save them separately?

```
graphnumber = 0;
AxesH = axes('Xlim', [0, 100], 'XTick', 0:10:100, 'NextPlot', 'add');

plot(normV2, 'linewidth',2,'color','r')
hold on
plot(normV3, 'linewidth',2,'color','b')
hold off
hold on
plot(normV4, 'linewidth',2,'color','g')
hold off

legend('n = 2','n = 3','n = 4', 'location','northeast')
title('||Lambda^k||','fontsize',12,'fontweight','b')
outfilename = ['graph' num2str(graphnumber)];
print('-djpeg',outfilename)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your data properly by creating a cell array. Then loop over it, and create a figure for each `normV` element:

```
data = {normV2, normV3, normV4};

f = figure;
AxesH = axes(f, 'Xlim', [0, 100], 'XTick', 0:10:100);
title(AxesH, '||Lambda^k||','fontsize',12,'fontweight','b');

for i = 1:numel(data)

    p = plot(AxesH, data{i}, 'linewidth',2,'color','r');
    legend(AxesH, ['n = ' num2str(i + 1)], 'location','northeast');
    outfilename = ['graph' num2str(i - 1)];
    print('-djpeg',outfilename);
    clf(p); % Clear axes of plot

end
```

Comment: actually, normV2 is a vector with 100 elements, so if I do the way you are sayin, it does not work here because data(i) does not give the vector

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next code to print and save:

```
figure;plot(normV2, 'linewidth',2,'color','r');
saveas(gcf,'normV2.jpeg');
figure;plot(normV3, 'linewidth',2,'color','b');
saveas(gcf,'normV3.jpeg');
figure;plot(normV4, 'linewidth',2,'color','g');
saveas(gcf,'normV4.jpeg');
```